# way to find a current value of a symbol and rounnd it off to nearest 100 with decimal place using Pinescript

Tags: pine-script

I am looking for a Pinescript code which should find the current price of teh symbol. For example if the latest price of a symbol is 42349.15 then i should be able to round it off to nearest 100 that is 42300 and upto one decimal place ie 42300.0.

So my current price is 42349.15 and the final output in a new variable should be 42300.0
Thanks in advance.

I tried round function but that seems not working in Pinescript

Comment: Divide by 100 then Math.round() should do your job